# Optimization to find complex number as input

Tags: c++, c, matlab, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I am wondering if there is a C/C++ library or Matlab code technique to determine real and complex numbers using a minimization solver.  Here is a code snippet showing what I would like to do.  For example, suppose that I know `Utilde`, but not `x` and `U` variables.  I want to use optimization (`fminsearch`) to determine `x` and `U`, given `Utilde`.  Note that `Utilde` is a complex number.

```
x = 1.5;
U = 50 + 1i*25;
x0 = [1 20];  % starting values
Utilde = U * (1 / exp(2 * x)) * exp( 1i * 2 * x);
xout = fminsearch(@(v)optim(v, Utilde), x0);

function diff = optim(v, Utilde)
x = v(1);
U = v(2);
diff =  abs( -(Utilde/U) + (1 / exp(2 * x)) * exp( 1i * 2 * x  ) );
```

The code above does not converge to the proper values, and `xout = 1.7318   88.8760`.  However, if  `U = 50`, which is not a complex number, then `xout = 1.5000   50.0000`, which are the proper values.

Is there a way in Matlab or C/C++ to ensure proper convergence, given `Utilde` as a complex number?  Maybe I have to change the code above?

- If there isn't a way to do this natively in Matlab, then perhaps one
  gist of the question is this: Is there a multivariate (i.e.
  Nelder-Mead or similar algorithm) optimization library that is able
  to work with real and complex inputs and outputs?
- Yet another question is whether the function is convergent or not.  I
  don't know if it is the algorithm or the function.  Might I need to change something in the `Utilde = U * (1 / exp(2 * x)) * exp( 1i * 2 * x)` expression to make it convergent?

Comment: From my experience: using these built-in minimization procedures often gives you more headaches than it helps. If you definitely need to do it this way, I would stick to Python - with MATLAB it will probably not be better.

Comment: Sure - what is the best way in Python to set up this optimization problem?  Is there a tool for Python that can optimize using complex numbers?

Comment: @NicholasKinar I am a little bit uncertain about the arithmetic rules for complex numbers right now, but if you only want to retrieve the topmost `x` and `U` values in the optimization, would it not be more appropriate to specify `diff` as `diff =  abs( Utilde - U * (1 / exp(2 * x)) * exp( 1i * 2 * x  ) )`? Or better still from a differentiation point of view the difference squared instead of the absolute difference?

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: Thanks for your comment. Hmm...I tried this, and I still can't reach convergence for all `x` and `U`.  For example, `x = 7` and `U = 10`.  Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @NicholasKinar I have looked a little further at this problem and provided an answer. Please have a look to see if you agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that there is no unique solution to this optimization or parameter fitting problem. For example, looking at the expected and actual results above, `Utilde` is equivalent (ignoring round-off differences) for the two (`x`, `U`) pairs, i.e.

```
Utilde(x = 1.5, U = 50 + 25i) = Utilde(x = 1.7318, U = 88.8760)
```

Although I have not examined it in depth, I even suspect that for any value of `x`, you can find an `U` that computes to `Utilde(x, U) = Utilde(x = 1.5, U = 50 + 25i)`.

The solution here would thus be to further constrain the parameter fitting problem so that the solver yields *any* solution that can be considered acceptable. Alternatively, reformulate `Utilde` to have a unique value for any (`x`, `U`) pair.

**UPDATE, AUG 1**

Given reasonable starting values, it actually seems like it is sufficient to restrict `x` to be real-valued. Performing unconstrained non-linear optimization using the `diff` function formulated above, I get the following result:

```
x = 1.50462926953244
U = 50.6977768845879 + 24.7676554234729i
diff = 3.18731710515855E-06
```

However, changing the starting guess to values more distant from the desired values does  yield different solutions, so restricting `x` to be real-values does not alone provide a unique solution to the problem.

I have implemented this in C#, using the [BOBYQA](https://github.com/cureos/csbobyqa) optimizer, but the numerics should be the same as above. If you want to try outside of Matlab, it should also be relatively simple to turn the C# code below into C++ code using the [std::complex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/complex/) class and an (unconstrained) nonlinear C++ optimizer of your own choice. You could find some C++ compatible codes that do not require gradient computation [here](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/nlounres.html#function), and there is also various implementations available in Numerical Recipes. For example, you could access the C version of NR online [here](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html).

For reference, here are the relevant parts of my C# code:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Complex Coeff = new Complex(-2.0, 2.0);
    private static readonly Complex UTilde0 = GetUTilde(1.5, new Complex(50.0, 25.0));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double[] vars = new[] {1.0, 25.0, 0.0}; // xstart = 1.0, Ustart = 25.0
        BobyqaExitStatus status = Bobyqa.FindMinimum(GetObjfnValue, vars.Length, vars);
    }

    public static Complex GetUTilde(double x, Complex U)
    {
        return U * Complex.Exp(Coeff * x);
    }

    public static double GetObjfnValue(int n, double[] vars)
    {
        double x = vars[0]; 
        Complex U = new Complex(vars[1], vars[2]);
        return Complex.Abs(-UTilde0 / U + Complex.Exp(Coeff * x));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your insightful answer.  How might I reformulate `Utilde` to have a unique value for any `(x, U)` pair?

Comment: @NicholasKinar What is `Utilde` meant to represent? Can you link to some context where this is illustrated?

Comment: Utilde (as a complex number) is the output of a product of two numbers in the frequency domain.  The `(1 / exp(2 * x)) * exp( 1i * 2 * x)` is the filter kernel, and the `U` is a Gabor transformed signal.  This is a seismic Q filtering application, and there is a similar equation on pg. 128 of the book Seismic Inverse Q filtering: http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING.  Could you suggest a good reference book on this type of optimization problem?  Maybe if `U` is unknown, this is a blind deconvolution problem?

Comment: The real part of the expression can be found on pg. 67 of the book, as Equation (4.22) and Equation (4.20).  Moreover, the `Utilde` expression is on pg. 128 as Equation (7.21).  The `U` is a Gabor-transformed seismic input trace.

Comment: @NicholasKinar Oh boy! Those were quite _complex_ (pun intended :-) expressions. It is not immediately obvious to me how to deal with these expressions in a parameter fitting scenario (in fact I cannot even see straight away that your `Utilde` corresponds to those equations). In order to go forward I think you need to consider the following: in a real fitting scenario you would only have `Utilde`, right? Does it matter which pair of `x` and `U` that satisfies this `Utilde`? In that case, what are the restrictions on either of the `x` and `U` parameters?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, Anders.  I have a physical copy of that particular book, and some of the pages are getting very worn through with continued use.  Yes, it does matter which pair of `x` and `U` satisfies the `Utilde`, and suppose that we place restrictions on the `x` and `U` parameters, such that the real and complex parts of `x` and `U` are within two values.  How do I place these restrictions?  Can you suggest a book detailing how to do this?

Comment: So perhaps placing limits on `x` and `U` would be the way to go?  At least, `x` must be between a higher and lower limit, and `U` must be between a higher and lower limit.

Comment: Yes, I would start in this direction. Maybe there are even further restrictions, i.e. that `x` should be real-valued?

Comment: Yes, `x` should be real-valued as well.  What numerical procedure or algorithm would be the best to do the optimization with these restrictions?

Comment: @NicholasKinar Please see my encouraging :-) update to this answer.

Comment: That's just lovely.  Thank you so much for this great answer!  Three questions: (1) I am wondering if the starting values for `x` and `U` have to be sufficiently "close" to the optimization values; (2) How does your code restrict `x` to be real-valued; and (3) Could you suggest any reasonably good "cross-platform" C++ optimization library that I can use for this problem as well?

Comment: Or perhaps I could use Mono with your BOBYQA optimizer.

Comment: See further update of the answer, in particular I have emphasized `x` to be real-valued (`double`). If you are running on Mac or Linux and it is otherwise no problem for you to develop in C#, then yes, go for Mono.

Comment: Thanks, Anders; this is very much appreciated.  Thank you for giving me an excellent framework and code for this problem.  I will experiment with the exponential function argument a little bit more and then get back to you.

Comment: After much experimentation, I've found that `x` and `U` need to be close to the actual values, and the framework that you've provided is the best answer to this question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for `fminsearch` says how to deal with complex numbers in the [limitations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fminsearch.html) section:

> `fminsearch` only minimizes over the real numbers, that is, `x` must only consist of real numbers and `f(x)` must only return real numbers. When `x` has complex variables, they must be split into real and imaginary parts.

You can use the functions [`real`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/real.html) and [`imag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imag.html) to extract the real and imaginary parts, respectively.

Comment: Actually, this probably doesn't help here since your function returns a complex output for a real input. If your function were real-valued, though, then I think that this method would work.

Comment: Isn't the `diff` variable always real since this is the absolute value of a complex number?  If this is the case, then how do I split into real and imaginary parts?

Comment: @NicholasKinar You're right. Your function seems to take real inputs and be real-valued. Why do you say that `fminsearch` isn't converging properly with complex `Utilde`? Did you find the minimum analytically?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if this is a problem with the function, or if there is another issue here.  I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no easy way to do this, even if both `x` and `U` are real numbers.  The equation for `Utilde` is not well-posed for an optimization problem, and so it must be modified.

I've tried to code up my own version of the Nelder-Mead optimization algorithm, as well as tried Powell's method.  Neither seem to work well for this problem, even when I attempted to modify these methods.