# A stand alone software using fortran / C/ C++

Tags: c++, c, fortran, mathematical-optimization

I need to build a **standalone Windows-based software**, using the **Fortran and or  C/C ++**. I expect users to download the program, install it and use it generically in a Windows environment.

Main aim of the software is to perform **complex nonlinear optimization**, and possibly **constrained optimization**.  I expect users to interact with the program using a highly interactive graphics user interface. Practically, depicting results user high-end graphics is a necessity.

I want to know whether it is possible to achieve these using freely available libraries for Fortran/C/C++.

Comment: Do you mean **complex** as in _complex numbers_, or _difficult_?

Comment: There are many freely available 2D and 3D plotting libraries as well as many optimisation engines. Mixing Fortran for the computational stuff and C/C++ for the GUI is entirely possible. Building a self-contained distributable is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

Many, if not most, of the (freely available) open source optimization codes are written in Fortran and or C/C++. For a quick overview, please have a look at Hans Mittelmann's [Decision Tree for Optimization Software](http://plato.asu.edu/sub/pns.html).

There is also the [COIN-OR Foundation](http://www.coin-or.org/), which hosts many optimization codes (most written in C/C++, I believe) and support tools. You can find the list of available projects [here](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/).

If by *complex* optimization you refer to *complex numbers*, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11474970/650012) SO question for further elaboration on how to formulate optimization problems involving complex numbers.

Comment: Hi Anders, many thanks for your reply. I would also like to know whether it is possible to call them independently in my software which I am going to build. Also complex optimization is in nature but not for complex numbers. Thanks once again. Regards, rehena

Comment: Not sure what you mean by calling them independently? The codes usually expose different API:s, so you will most certainly need to write wrapper methods to be able to call them all using the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Fortran to write routines for computation and transform everything into a dll.
The application can be written in C++ (for example GUI in Qt).
For visualization there are good libraries in C++, like VTK, otherwise you can use OpenGl.
If you want numerical libraries additionally, you can use LAPACK for example.